# How do I reset array content

Tags: asp.net, arrays, c#-4.0, razor, webmatrix

I'm using @RenderPage passing an array:

```
@RenderPage("/Shared/_ScopeFormControls.cshtml", ChangeScope)
```

The array is declared and set initially as:

```
string[,] ChangeScope = { { "True" }, { "" }, { "" } };
```

The receiving page deconstructs the array into variables to use in its own if statements:

```
string[,] ChangeScope = PageData[0];   
var isValid = ChangeScope[0,0];
var InvsOut = ChangeScope[1,0];   
var ItemsToMoveIDs = ChangeScope[2,0];
```

That all works fine when the page is first loaded.

I'd like to reset the content of the array inside the if (IsPost) dependent on a bunch of if statements then the Renderpage would be recalled with the new values.

Basically I'd like to use the array like a normal variable and overwrite its existing content with new content, something like:

```
ChangeScope = { { "True" }, { "IntoScope" }, { ItemsToMoveIDs } };
```

Is this possible?

Comment: You have to say `ChangeScope = new string[,] { ... }`. The `new string[,]` is essential.

Answer (score 1):

Are you really looking for something as simple as:

```
if (IsPost)
{
    ChangeScope = new string[,] { { "True" }, { "" }, { "" } };
}
```

Comment: Yes, that is essentially what I have but it does not compile. it says: only assignment, call, increment, decrement, and new object expressions can be used as a statement.

Comment: @CharlotteCopper: Then post the code that you do have and maybe we can help you figure out why you're getting an error.

Answer (score 0):

Try using Array.Clear().

More information can be found on MSDN [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.array.clear.aspx).